# Filter only on first 3 letters in combobox in extjs

Tags: extjs, combobox

I have a ComboBox that displays like the code in the description.

Example:
CAS(Direct)
ECS(Consolidated). When I am searching `ec`, it should give me the ECS as the first result but it's giving CAS(direct) as the first result because `ec` is present in cas(direct) as well. I want to search and retrieve the results only in the first 3 letters.

expected result: when I search `ec`, it should give me the first result as ECS(consolidated).

```
Ext.define('App.View.Component.Filter.ServiceLevel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.App-View-Component-Filter-ServiceLevel',
    labelAlign: 'right',
    emptyText: 'Service Level',
    valueField: 'code',
    displayField: 'decode',
    forceSelection: true,
    anyMatch: true,
    allowBlank: false,
    queryMode: 'local',
    hideTrigger: false,
    store: {
        fields: ['decode', 'code'],
        autoLoad: true,
        data: [
            { decode: 'CAS (Direct)', code: 'CA' },
            { decode: 'ECS (Consolidated)', code: 'EC' }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the combobox method called `doLocalQuery`.

Combobox doesn't have a possibility to change `startsWith` and `endsWith` parameters in local queries.

Look on example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ucc

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I am looking for.